# Where is the Wrapper Assembly Key File setting in VS 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, com-interop, strongname, typelib, tlbimp

I'm trying to build an application that is strongly named.  It is referencing a COM interop library that I add via the Add References dialog.  It's been a while, but I seem to recall that in older versions of visual studio, there was a project setting for *Wrapper Assembly Key File*.  I can't seem to find it in Visual Studio 2008?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across your post looking for the same thing, but found a different route on my own to get around the issue of strong naming a COM Interop referenced assembly.

You can sign the imported type library assembly with the key file before you reference it in Visual Studio by using the `/keyfile:<key.snk>` parameter:

```
tlbimp MyCOMService.tlb /out:Interop.MyCOMService.dll /keyfile:MyKeyFile.snk
```

Comment: I used this post to guide me (a newbie) through the process: http://buffered.io/2008/07/09/net-fu-signing-an-unsigned-assembly-without-delay-signing/